# about minimal non-nilpotent groups

Tags: group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Newman and Wiegold have studied the AN-groups i.e. the locally nilpotent groups which are not nilpotent but every proper subgroup is nilpotent.
I was asking why the notion locally nilpotent was added to the definition, because if every subgroup is nilpotent then the group will be certainly locally nilpotent.
Thank you.

Comment: Locally "something"means that every *finitely generated* subgroup has this property "something".

Comment: yes, I know but I d'ont understand why they added locally nilpotent to the definition because if every subgroup is nilpotent then so are the finitely generated which means that the group is locally nilpotent.

Comment: Hmm, I am reading the paper now http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01589192#page-1 and they say that AN-groups are by definition **not finitely generated**. But you are right, since every *proper* subgroup is by definition nilpotent, it follows that AN-groups are locally nilpotent. This is important, since a lot is known about this class of groups. So that maybe the reason to note this explicitly.

Comment: Or may be they need some proprities of locally nilpotent groups to use it in proofs because there are some lemmas of locally nilpotent groups. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. And being infinitely generated is important. Since a finitely generated subgroup must be *proper*, it is nilpotent. So the definition of AN groups is quite subtle.

Comment: ok, thank you very much :)